# Jquery remove attribute from element before current

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Here Is My Code

```
<a target="_blank" href="/pics/2016/03/21/56efb593855ae56efb5938599556efb59385d80.jpg" title="Click For Larger View">
 <img src="/pics/2016/03/21/56efb593855ae56efb5938599556efb59385d80.jpg" width="150px" height="150px" id="post-img" class="post-img">
</a>
```

Is there a way in jQuery to to get the remove the `href` element from the element above the `.post-img` class.

So in theory I want it to turn out like:

```
<a target="_blank" title="Click For Larger View">
 <img src="/pics/2016/03/21/56efb593855ae56efb5938599556efb59385d80.jpg" width="150px" height="150px" id="post-img" class="post-img">
</a>
```

and this can be done; just by having the class (`.post-img`) of the element inside of the `a`(link).

!!!HOWEVER CAN THIS BE DONE!!!

Please could you help me I am not that good with `Javascript` or`Jquery`!!!

Comment: Check out http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeattribute.asp

Answer (score 0):

Get the parent using [`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) method and then remove href using [`removeAttr()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/).

```js
$('.post-img').parent().removeAttr('href');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a target="_blank" title="Click For Larger View" href="/pics/2016/03/21/56efb593855ae56efb5938599556efb59385d80.jpg">
    <img src="/pics/2016/03/21/56efb593855ae56efb5938599556efb59385d80.jpg" width="150px" height="150px" id="post-img" class="post-img">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 // select the parent of img with parent()
 var a = $('img.post-img').parent();
 a.removeAttr('href');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sra9sndm/